# While Loop keeps crashing

Tags: python, loops, input, while-loop

I'm new to Python, Ive only done a little bit at University as I study Cyber sec. I'm trying to write a small script for work (personal Use). The code won't loop and it keeps crashing, Can anyone help?

```
"""
Created on Fri Apr 16 10:28:50 2021

@author: lukem
"""

import datetime
from datetime import *
import sys

print("Commercial Divers Work Hours")
while True:
    while True:
        
                DT1 = input("Is it todays date?:").lower()
                
            
                if DT1 == 'n' or DT1 == 'N':
                   DT2 = input("Enter Date?")
                
                elif DT1 == 'Y' or DT1 == 'y':
                      print(datetime.now())
                      
               
                
                   
                shrs = int(input("Start Time?:"))
                fhrs = int(input("Finish time?:"))
                thrs = int(input("Travel time?:"))
                job = input("At what Job?:")
                dp = input("Depth pay? How many meters?:")
                wd = input("Welding allowance? y/n:")
                    
                    
                if wd == 'y':
                
                    wd1 =  int(input("How Many Millimeters?:"))
                 
                    
                elif wd == 'n':
                    print("0")
                    break 
                                     
    
                 
                if DT1 == 'Y' or  DT1 == 'y':
                 
                   print("Date: ",datetime.now())
                   print("Start Time: ",shrs)
                   print("Finish Time: ",fhrs)
                   print("Travel Time: ",thrs)
                   print("Job or Client: ",job)
                   print("Depth Allowance in meters: ",dp)
                   print("Welding allowance in mm: ", wd1)
                   
                elif DT1 == 'n' or DT1 == 'N':
                    
                   print("Date: ",DT2)
                   print("Start Time: ",shrs)
                   print("Finish Time: ",fhrs)
                   print("Travel Time: ",thrs)
                   print("Job or Client: ",job)
                   print("Depth Allowance in meters: ",dp)
                   print("Welding allowance in mm: ", wd1)
                        
                        
                   
                    
                   
                file = open('Workhours7y.txt' , 'a')
                sys.stdout = file 
                      
                if DT1 == 'Y' or  DT1 == 'y':
                     
                       print("Date: ",datetime.now())
                       print("Start Time: ",shrs)
                       print("Finish Time: ",fhrs)
                       print("Travel Time: ",thrs)
                       print("Job or Client: ",job)
                       print("Depth Allowance in meters: ",dp)
                       print("Welding allowance in mm: ", wd1)
                       
                elif DT1 == 'n' or DT1 == 'N':
                        
                       print("Date: ",DT2)
                       print("Start Time: ",shrs)
                       print("Finish Time: ",fhrs)
                       print("Travel Time: ",thrs)
                       print("Job or Client: ",job)
                       print("Depth Allowance in meters: ",dp)
                       print("Welding allowance in mm: ", wd1)
                
                file.close()
                
                Continue
```

Comment: What's the full error, complete with stack trace?

Comment: [SpyderKernelApp] ERROR | Exception in message handler:

ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.

Comment: There is about 100 lines of jargon in Spyder but this is the firstand last line.

Comment: btw You could just check if `DT1.lower() == 'n'` so You don't have to write to comparisons

Comment: You're closing the replaced `stdout`, then attempting to write to it. Why are you doing `sys.stdout = file`? Why not just write to the file normally, or use the `file` parameter of `print`?

Comment: Says this in IDLE - Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\lukem\OneDrive\Desktop\Workhrsscript.py", line 16, in <module>
    DT1 = input("Is it todays date?:").lower()
ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.
>>>

Comment: also could just use with statement

Comment: Im not sure - My main goal is to print the inputs to the .txt file in a loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're getting this error because you're making `sys.stdout` point to `file`, then you close `file`. The problem is, `print` writes to whatever file is pointed to by `sys.stdout`, but you've closed that file.

Get rid of the `sys.stdout = file` line and instead, either change your `print`s to use the `file` parameter:

```
print("Date: ",DT2, file=file)
```

Or, just write to the file directly:

```
file.write(f"Date: {DT2}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't sys.stdout = file.
At the end you close the file and when the loop starts from the beginning you still try to print to the closed file, which doesn't work because it's closed.

Write to the file using a separate command.